# Expose Calcite based db through Avatica by custom servlet

Tags: java, jdbc, jira, apache-calcite

I have built my custom schema with calcite help. Now I would like to expose it through servlet and connect to it with Avatica. I am using servlet because my container is JIRA. Here is some relevant code from servlet

```
public class JDBCServlet extends HttpServlet {

private final Service service;
private final ProtobufHandler pbHandler;
private final ProtobufTranslation protobufTranslation;
private final MetricsSystem metrics;

final ThreadLocal<UnsynchronizedBuffer> threadLocalBuffer;

public JDBCServlet(LocalDBProvider provider) {
    this.service = provider.service();
    this.metrics = provider.metrics();
    this.protobufTranslation = new ProtobufTranslationImpl();
    this.pbHandler = new ProtobufHandler(service, protobufTranslation, metrics);
    this.threadLocalBuffer = new ThreadLocal<UnsynchronizedBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public UnsynchronizedBuffer initialValue() {
            return new UnsynchronizedBuffer();
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("DO GET DO GET");
    doPost(req, resp);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("DO POST DO POST");
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    final byte[] requestBytes;
    // Avoid a new buffer creation for every HTTP request
    final UnsynchronizedBuffer buffer = threadLocalBuffer.get();
    try (ServletInputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream()) {
        requestBytes = AvaticaUtils.readFullyToBytes(inputStream, buffer);
    } finally {
        buffer.reset();
    }

    Handler.HandlerResponse<byte[]> handlerResponse;
    try {
        handlerResponse = pbHandler.apply(requestBytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handlerResponse = pbHandler.convertToErrorResponse(e);
    }
    response.setStatus(handlerResponse.getStatusCode());
    response.getOutputStream().write(handlerResponse.getResponse());
    response.getOutputStream().close();
}
}
```

Code is based on AvaticaProtobufHandler withouth Jetty related stuff.

Service is built using LocalService and CalciteConnection with my custom schema:

```
new LocalService(DRIVER.createMeta((AvaticaConnection) bootstrap.getConnection()));
```

When connecting with squirrel (with avatica jars:) with url:
   jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http://127.0.0.1:2990/jira/plugins/servlet/smartqljdbctest;serialization=PROTOBUF

a couple of HTTP POST request is handshaked with the driver but the whole things fails on Meta.toProto() method:

```
    } else {
      // Can a "row" be a primitive? A struct? Only an Array?
      throw new RuntimeException("Only arrays are supported");
    }
```

I assume that I've bootstrapped the servlet wrong, but don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

After messing with Calcite I've managed to handle this using JDBCMeta from Evatica Server example.

From my previous solution I think that Meta produced by a Driver based on CalciteConnection is not compatible with avatica LocalService implementation.

Comment: can you please tell more details about how you did it with the JDBCMeta from Avatica ? Are you sure it's not possible ? :(